# Como criar uma tabela de seguidores?

Tags: mysql

Estou fazendo um projeto de tcc, projeto esse que é meio que uma rede social..., é quero criar um sistema de seguidores mas não sei como colocar isso no banco de dados ou como relacionar os dados que já tenho

esta e a tabela de usuário

```
 CREATE TABLE usuario(
    id_usuario      SMALLINT     AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome            VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    sobrenome       VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    apelido         VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
    email           VARCHAR (60) NOT NULL,
    senha           VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
    numero          VARCHAR (11),
    id_status       VARCHAR(4), 
    data_nascimento DATE         NOT NULL,
    cpf             VARCHAR (11),
    
    CONSTRAINT pk_id_usuario PRIMARY KEY (id_usuario),
    CONSTRAINT fk_id_status  FOREIGN KEY (id_status) REFERENCES status (id_status)
);
```

e esta é a tabela do artista

```
 CREATE TABLE artista(
    id_artista  SMALLINT     AUTO_INCREMENT,
    descricao   VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    id_usuario  SMALLINT     NOT NULL,
    -- seguidores  INT, -- 
    rede_social VARCHAR(200),
    
    
    CONSTRAINT pk_id_artista PRIMARY KEY (id_artista),
    CONSTRAINT fk_id_usuario_artista FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario) REFERENCES usuario (id_usuario)
);
```

Não sei como fazer tal relacionamento já que o artista também é um usuário.

Comment: Eu armazenaria AB e BA. Uma 'amizade' é realmente um relacionamento de mão dupla, cada entidade está ligada a outra. Embora intuitivamente pensemos na "amizade" como um elo entre duas pessoas, do ponto de vista relacional, é mais como "A tem um amigo B" e "B tem um amigo A". Dois relacionamentos, dois registros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que a melhor alternativa seria criar uma terceira tabela contendo um relação N/M de usuário/artista

```
CREATE TABLE seguidores (
    id_artista  SMALLINT,
    id_usuario  SMALLINT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_id_seguidores_usuario FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario) REFERENCES usuario (id_usuario),
    CONSTRAINT fk_id_seguidores_artista FOREIGN KEY (id_artista) REFERENCES artista (id_artista)
 );
```

Ai caso queira contar quantos seguidores um artista tem basta

```
SELECT COUNT(id_artista) WHERE id_artista = IdDoArtistaRequerido FROM seguidores;
```

Comment: vlw pela dica, só o SELECT que não entendi muito bem  mas isso eu dou um jeito aqui